# IUP graphic examples issue

Tags: iup

I have been trying to run the IUP graphic examples given under this link  [C or CPP examples](http://webserver2.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/examples/C/)

such as plot.C  or mathglsamples.c under the MinGW X64 windows environment straight out of the source code adaption without modification per se. However the documentation is so poor that I ran into wall.  After repeated attempts I finally get it going with IUP , CD and IM core dynamic library .

I am now happily sharing my successful configuration for standalone exe file to benefit and help  those to avoid facing  frustration and  error  as there are no explicit library requirements currently  shared in the website.

It would be much easier to run this on the netbeans IDE just specify all those header files and library required .

Below is the Cmake , just have to ensure all those .dll library are copy into the same output folder where exe files are located .

```
# cmake_minimum_required(VERSION <specify CMake version here>)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)
project(IUP)
#set (CMAKE_LEGACY_CYGWIN_WIN32 0)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)



set(IUPDir "C:/iup-3.24_Win64_dllw4_lib")
set(CDDir "C:/cd-5.11.1_Win64_dllw4_lib")
set (IMDir "C:/im-3.12_Win64_dllw4_lib")


include_directories(${IUPDir})
include_directories(${IUPDir}/include)

include_directories(CDDir)
include_directories(${CDDir}/include)

include_directories(${IMDir}/include)

link_directories(${IUPDir})
link_directories(${CDDir})


add_executable(IUP mathglsamples.c)
#add_executable(IUP plot.cpp)

find_package(iup.dll)
find_package(iupimglib.dll)


add_custom_command(TARGET IUP POST_BUILD        # Adds a post-build event to MyTest
        COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different  # which executes "cmake - E copy_if_different..."
        "${IUPDir}/iup.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupimglib.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iup_plot.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupcontrols.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupgl.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupcd.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/ftgl.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iup_mglplot.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupim.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/zlib1.dll"

        "${CDDir}/cd.dll"
        "${CDDir}/cdgl.dll"
        "${CDDir}/freetype6.dll"
        "${CDDir}/cdcontextplus.dll"


        "${IMDir}/im.dll"
        "${IMDir}/im_process.dll"
        # <--this is in-file
        $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:IUP>

        )

target_include_directories(IUP PUBLIC ${IUPDir})
target_include_directories(IUP PUBLIC ${CDDir})
target_include_directories(IUP PUBLIC ${IMDir})


target_link_libraries (IUP  PUBLIC

        "${IUPDir}/iup.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupimglib.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iup_plot.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupcontrols.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupgl.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupcd.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/ftgl.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iup_mglplot.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/iupim.dll"
        "${IUPDir}/zlib1.dll"

        "${CDDir}/cd.dll"
        "${CDDir}/cdgl.dll"
        "${CDDir}/freetype6.dll"
        "${CDDir}/cdcontextplus.dll"


        "${IMDir}/im.dll"
        "${IMDir}/im_process.dll"


        )
```

thanks

Answer (score 0):

> there are no explicit library requirements currently shared in the website

That's not true. There are lots of documentation for building IUP applications in the IUP website (including a tutorial and guides for several IDEs):

http://iup.sourceforge.net/
or
http://www.tecgraf.puc-rio.br/iup/

For a plot example, the complexity is increased a lot, because involves several libraries. To use the DLLs instead of static libraries also complicates. But the dependencies are there. To state that:

> the documentation is so poor

Really undermine our work. I suggest you that when contributing to any open source library, start with "the documentation is missing that ...".

If you find some dependencies that are not described, please let us know. You can communicate issues using the iup@tecgraf.puc-rio.br email or in our mailing list.

Thanks for sharing your CMake makefile.

Comment: Sorry , unless you can  point to a very precise documentation on this , I would still think the IUP written narration is still very damn poor , why there is no simple run time build  guide on how to run those examples  being written in the first place , why must the user need to figure out through repeated debug process to determine   what are those damn library needed to run those graphic examples  ?